# Running multiple virtual hosts

Tags: apache-2.2, domain, virtualhost

I want to run multiple domains on my server (only two at the moment). I already changed both nameservers to point to my server.

In the apache2.conf file I enabled "included sites-enabled".

My ports.conf file looks as follows

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
Listen 80
Listen 443

<VirtualHost xx.xx.xx.xx:443>
    SSLEngine On
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.key

    ServerAdmin admin@firstDomain.com
    ServerName firstDomain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/
    ErrorLog /var/log/error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

This is the setting for my main page.

My httpd.conf file looks like this

```
ServerName firstDomain.com

<VirtualHost xx.xx.xx.xx:80>
ServerAdmin admin@firstDomain.com
ServerName firstDomain.com
DocumentRoot /var/www/
ErrorLog /var/log/error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName secondDomain.com
    ServerAlias *.secondDomain.com
    DocumentRoot /home/user/www/secondDomain.com/htdocs
</VirtualHost>

Options -Indexes All FollowSymLinks MultiViews
```

Last but not least my "secondDomain" file in "sites-avaiable"

```
<VirtualHost secondDomain.com>
    ServerAdmin user@firstDomain.com
    ServerName  secondDomain.com

    # Indexes + Directory Root.
    DirectoryIndex index.html
    DocumentRoot /home/user/www/secondDomain/htdocs/

    # CGI Directory
    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /home/user/www/seoncDomain/cgi-bin/
    <Location /cgi-bin>
            Options +ExecCGI
    </Location>


    # Logfiles
    ErrorLog  /home/user/www/secondDomain/logs/error.log
    CustomLog /home/user/www/secondDomain/logs/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

I also get an error message, everytime I restart the apache server, saying that VirtualHosts xx.xx.xx.xx:80 overlaps with VirtualHosts xx.xx.xx.xx:80.

When I call my secondDomain.com only the firstDomain.com pops up. It seems like the mapping is wrong.

apachectl -t output:

```
[warn] VirtualHost xx.xx.xx.xx:80 overlaps with VirtualHost xx.xx.xx.xx:80, the first has   precedence, perhaps you need a NameVirtualHost directive
Syntax OK
```

apache2ctl -S output:

```
[Wed Feb 29 02:05:17 2012] [warn] VirtualHost xx.xx.xx.xx:80 overlaps with VirtualHost xx.xx.xx.xx:80, the first has precedence, perhaps you need a NameVirtualHost directive
VirtualHost configuration:
127.0.0.1:*           secondDomain.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/secondDomain.com:1)
xx.xx.xx.xx:443       firstDomain.com (/etc/apache2/ports.conf:12)
xx.xx.xx.xx:80        firstDomain.com (/etc/apache2/httpd.conf:3)
wildcard NameVirtualHosts and _default_ servers:
*:80                   is a NameVirtualHost
     default server secondDomain.com (/etc/apache2/httpd.conf:11)
     port 80 namevhost secondDomain.com (/etc/apache2/httpd.conf:11)
     port 80 namevhost firstDomain.com (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default:1)
     port 80 namevhost firstDomain.com (/etc/apache2/apache2.conf:241)
     port 80 namevhost secondDomain.com (/etc/apache2/apache2.conf:249)
Syntax OK
```

Wordpress is installed through apt-get. I have a symlink in /var/www/ which points to /usr/share/wordpress and activated in /etc/apache2/sites-available and a2ensite.

Comment: can you run `apachectl -t` and paste any errors you see?

Comment: edited post with apachectl -t output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a `NameVirtualHost` directive, but you're not using it.  You're specifying the IP address and/or the hostname in your `<VirtualHost>` declaration - that's not what you want.

Change:

```
<VirtualHost xx.xx.xx.xx:80>
```

and

```
<VirtualHost secondDomain.com>
```

To both be simply:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
```

Comment: This fixed the error output, when calling apachectl -t, but somehow now the firstdomain.com maps to my wordpress install, which lies in www/wordpress, although that's not what I want. Therefore I changed the values back to the IP address. I think something is completely messed up with my settings.

Comment: Where's your wordpress configured?  And what output do you get from `apache2ctl -S`?

Comment: edited first post with output.

Comment: @cherrun You have an three total vhosts that are configured to be `firstdomain.com`; the one in your `httpd.conf` file (which is empty by default in the Debian packaging that you're using) is getting precedence over the ones in `apache2.conf` and `sites-available/default`.  Get rid of the copies that shouldn't exist, and set all port 80 vhosts to the correct host specification as outlined in my answer.  You have vhost definitions sprinkled all over the place: `ports.conf`, `httpd.conf`, and `apache2.conf`, which is making things a lot more complicated than they need to be.

Comment: Which one is the correct file to write all the vhosts to? Is it alright that the ports.conf only have the Listen 80 and 443 option without specifying further vhosts?

Comment: Yes, that's all `ports.conf` is for.  You can really choose however you want to set it up, but if you want to follow the Debian package's conventions, create a new file for each vhost within `/etc/sites-available`, then when you want to turn it on use `a2ensite filename` to make a symlink for it in `/etc/sites-enabled`.

Comment: The thing I really don't get is why my apache is messed up, when I change the httpd.conf file for my firstDomain.com from xx.xx.xx.xx:80 to *:80. It just points to a completely different folder. I think I have to delete all conf files and start over.

Comment: If you change that, it will just use the one in `/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default` instead.  You should delete the duplicate host definitions first.

Answer (score 1):

You may try next:

1. Move firstDomain.com virtual host declaration to *sites-available/firstDomain*.
2. Remove everything from httpd.conf (you may try to define *ServerName* in *apache2.conf*)
3. Ensure that you have *sites-available/firstDomain* and *sites-available/secondDomain* symlinked to *sites-enabled/firstDomain* and *sites-enabled/secondDomain* respectively.